# Expected identifer or ')' Objective C

Tags: objective-c, sender, resignfirstresponder

```
(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender{//Expected identifer or ')'
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

What's wrong? It's an example from "Beginning iOS 6 Development"

Comment: Can you link to your source of "Beginning iOS 6 Development" or is it a book or something? Make sure you've got the most up-to-date version. When tutorials are broken (if it's the author's fault), they tend to get fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
-(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender{//Expected identifer or ')'
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

You skipped the - at the beginning, that identifies that there's a method there.

Answer (score 7):

You are missing a minus in front of your declaration:

```
-(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

It is not optional - a minus (for the instance methods) or a plus (for the class methods) is required by Objective C syntax.